# Fast code to determine if any two subsets of columns have the same sum

Tags: algorithm, performance, math, or-tools, constraint-programming

For a given n and m I iterate over all n by m partial [circulant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) matrices with entries that are either 0 or 1.  I want to find if there is a matrix such that there are no two subsets of the columns that give the same sum.  Here when we add columns we just do it elementwise.  My current code uses constraint programming via [ortools](https://code.google.com/p/or-tools/).  However it is not as fast I would like. For n = 7 and m = 12 it takes over 3 minutes and for n = 10, m = 18 it doesn't terminate even though there are only 2^18 = 262144 different matrices to consider.   Here is my code.

```
from scipy.linalg import circulant
import numpy as np
import itertools
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp as cs

n = 7
m = 12

def isdetecting(matrix):
    X = np.array([solver.IntVar(values) for i in range(matrix.shape[1])])
    X1 = X.tolist()
    for row in matrix:
        x = X[row].tolist()
        solver.Add(solver.Sum(x) == 0)
    db = solver.Phase(X1, solver.INT_VAR_DEFAULT, solver.INT_VALUE_DEFAULT)
    solver.NewSearch(db)
    count = 0
    while (solver.NextSolution() and count < 2):
        solution = [x.Value() for x in X1]
        count += 1
    solver.EndSearch()
    if (count < 2):
        return True

values = [-1,0,1]
solver = cs.Solver("scip")

for row in itertools.product([0,1],repeat = m):
    M = np.array(circulant(row)[0:n], dtype=bool)
    if isdetecting(M):
        print M.astype(int)
        break
```

Can this problem be solved fast enough so that n = 10, m = 18 can be solved?

Comment: I'd switch to a language with a faster compiler and apply brute force with some bit twiddling. 2^18 element distinctness computations with 2^18 64-bit integers sounds doable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you are declaring the "solver" variable globally and it seems to confuse or-tools to reuse it many times. When moving it inside "isdetecting", then the (7,12) problem is solved much faster, in about 7 seconds (compared to 2:51 minutes for the original model). I haven't checked it for the larger problem, though.

Also, it might be good idea to test different labelings (instead of solver.INT_VAR_DEFAULT and solver.INT_VALUE_DEFAULT), though binary value tend to be not very sensitive to different labelings. See the code for another labeling.

```
def isdetecting(matrix):
   solver = cs.Solver("scip") # <----
   X = np.array([solver.IntVar(values) for i in range(matrix.shape[1])])
   X1 = X.tolist()
   for row in matrix:
       x = X[row].tolist()
       solver.Add(solver.Sum(x) == 0)
   # db = solver.Phase(X1, solver.INT_VAR_DEFAULT, solver.INT_VALUE_DEFAULT)
   db = solver.Phase(X1, solver.CHOOSE_FIRST_UNBOUND, solver.ASSIGN_CENTER_VALUE)    
   solver.NewSearch(db)
   count = 0
   while (solver.NextSolution() and count < 2):
       solution = [x.Value() for x in X1]
       count += 1
   solver.EndSearch()
   if (count < 2):
       print "FOUND"
       return True
```

Edit: Here are constraints to remove the all-0 solutions as mentioned in the comments. What I know of, it require a separate list. It now takes a little longer (10.4s vs 7s).

```
X1Abs = [solver.IntVar(values, 'X1Abs[%i]' % i) for i in range(X1_len)]
for i in range(X1_len):
    solver.Add(X1Abs[i] == abs(X1[i])) 
solver.Add(solver.Sum(X1Abs) > 0)
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually my code is also strange in that I don't want "all zero" solutions but because I don't understand how to exclude them I check if there are 2 or more solutions. This is an ugly hack and it might even speed up the code to get rid of it.

Comment: (I hope I understand you correctly.) Try to add this constraint which sums all the values in the matrix: solver.Add(solver.Sum(X.flat) > 0)

Then a solution shows in 0.3s.

Comment: The variables in a solution can be -1, 0 or 1 so it would to be the sum of the absolute values. Can that be done?

Comment: Why does changing the labels speed it up?? (I just tested it and it indeed does.)

Comment: @user2179021: I'm not sure, but I think the speed up is because or-tools assumes that a Solver works with a single problem. When using it globally there can be some confusion with the constraints (and perhaps memory issues). Also, each time you closed the solver by EndSearch but didn't "open" it before and that is obviously not a good thing. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: That's a bogus constraint, actually.

Comment: @hakank Sorry I meant why does using db = solver.Phase(X1, solver.CHOOSE_FIRST_UNBOUND, solver.ASSIGN_CENTER_VALUE)  speed it up over db = solver.Phase(X1, solver.INT_VAR_DEFAULT, solver.INT_VALUE_DEFAULT) ?

Comment: @user2179021 In general different labelings prune the search tree in different ways (which is often very noticeable for larger domains). Though in this specific case I can't give you a detailed explanation why it's faster. I should say that I often try different labeling just to see what will happen.

Comment: @user2179021 I added the abs() constraint in the main answer.

Comment: @hakank Thank you. Using absolute values does seem slower than my hack strangely.  Maybe there is some more efficient way of doing this. (X1_len should be len(x1) I assume.)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Which constraint is bogus?

Comment: @user2179021 Yes, I meant len(X1). Perhaps it would be possible to use an AllDifferent constraint for solving this, which might speed up things since it's quite powerful. Exactly what do you mean by  "no two subsets of the columns that give the same sum"; is it among all the possible 2^m-1 subsets of the columns?

Comment: @hakank It is indeed. You can get examples by running my code of course :)

Comment: Your improved code (without the abs) took 3 hours for 10 by 18. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to choose another MIP solver (assuming that is what is used)?  I have gurobi installed which is normally very fast.

Comment: @user2179021 For using a MIP solver in or-tools, see this example: https://code.google.com/p/or-tools/source/browse/trunk/examples/python/diet1_mip.py . There are other examples in the same directory (search for "_mip.py"). I haven't yet tested Gurobi with or-tools/python.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is what I had in mind. I'd estimate the running time for command line parameters 10 18 at less than 8 hours on my machine.

```
public class Search {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int m = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int row = search(n, m);
        if (row >= 0) {
            printRow(m, row);
        }
    }

    private static int search(int n, int m) {
        if (n < 0 || m < n || m >= 31 || powOverflows(m + 1, n)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        long[] column = new long[m];
        long[] sums = new long[1 << m];
        int row = 1 << m;
        while (row-- > 0) {
            System.err.println(row);
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                column[j] = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    column[j] = (column[j] * (m + 1)) + ((row >> ((i + j) % m)) & 1);
                }
            }
            for (int subset = 0; subset < (1 << m); subset++) {
                long sum = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                    if (((subset >> j) & 1) == 1) {
                        sum += column[j];
                    }
                }
                sums[subset] = sum;
            }
            java.util.Arrays.sort(sums);
            boolean duplicate = false;
            for (int k = 1; k < (1 << m); k++) {
                if (sums[k - 1] == sums[k]) {
                    duplicate = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!duplicate) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return row;
    }

    private static boolean powOverflows(long b, int e) {
        if (b <= 0 || e < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        if (e == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        long max = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        while (e > 1) {
            if (b > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                return true;
            }
            if ((e & 1) == 1) {
                max /= b;
            }
            b *= b;
            e >>= 1;
        }
        return b > max;
    }

    private static void printRow(int m, int row) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            System.out.print((row >> j) & 1);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if the brute force method can be sped up. Say we fix the first half of the columns and iterate over just the second half. There is no need to recompute whether there are two subsets with the same sum entirely within the first half.  I wonder if this idea could save a lot of recomputation. Does this sound like a plausible speed up?

Comment: @user2179021 I thought about something along those lines. The problem is that, if we assume heuristically that the colliding subsets are rare and distributed uniformly at random, fully 3/4 of them will involve the last column, so it doesn't look as though there's a huge win waiting.